# Android contacts how can I keep track of specific phone numbers for contact

Tags: android, persistence, contacts

My app lets the user select a contact  using the contact picker. Afterward  lets user selects one or phone phone number to be stored for later use (the numbers are stored in the db)

The trivial solution would have been to save the selected numbers  to the database as strings. However I would like to avoid duplicating parts  of the  the device's contacts list and  keep a link (e.g. a URI to a particular number)  to that contact.

so far was not able to find a way to do that, the documentation states that  the contact id itself might change, So I can only assume it also true for the contacts  phone number.

am I missing something ?